# CollectionView populate at randomIndex in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a colllectionView running successfully which grabs url image content from web link .I am trying to populate collectionView at random index once every time view loads.my try as below...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 self.collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! Cell

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(apps.count)))

    cell.app = apps[randomIndex] as? AppInfo

    return cell
}
```

Above method reload the collectionView everytime page scrolls. I am trying to achieve reload once only...

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Anytime a cell scrolls off the screen it is de-initialized and then re-initialized right before it scrolls back into view. You may want to try and download and cache the images before running 'cellForItemAt' that way you can access them from memory when loading the cells instead of making a network call every time the cell is initialized.

Comment: `cellForItemAt indexPath` will call multiple times for same cell.

Comment: @Dustin Spengler where do i call this method...i am bit confused.

Comment: @Nirav D where do i call this method...i am bit confused

Comment: Hi there- if you only want to randomize the source data once, then I would not put the randomization code into cellForRowAtIndexPath. Do it earlier on when the view controller is initialized so it only gets called once. For instance you could pass the array as an argument for the viewController's init() method, randomize it before you store it, and that should solve your problem (Assuming I understand your question correctly!).